# Where are page permissions stored on hardware and how can I alter them directly?

Tags: windows, memory, x86-64, paging

I'm trying to write a pseudo kernel driver (it uses CVE 2018-8120 to get kernel permission so it's technically not a driver) and I want to be as safe as possible when entering ring0. I'm writing a function to read and write MSR's from userland, and before the transition to ring0 I'm trying to guarantee that the void pointer given to my function can be written, I decided the ideal way to do this was to make it writable if it is not already.

The problem is that the only way I know how to do this is with `VirtualProtect()` and `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`, but `VirtualProtect()` sometimes fails and returns an error instead. I want to know precisely where these access permissions are stored (in ram? in some special CPU register?) how I can obtain their address and how can I modify them directly?

Comment: You can't modify them directly, and shouldn't have to do so. If `VirtualProtect()` fails, there's a reason it's doing so and you can't circumvent it. You're trying to solve the Y part of an XY problem. The proper solution is to deal with X, which is to fix whatever you're doing wrong in the first place instead of trying to hack a way around the problem you're creating.

Comment: @KenWhite that's untrue or the operating system wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Um, no. The OS can do anything it wants. It's in charge. What other code can do it can control as well.

Comment: @KenWhite That's what I just said... I don't think you understood my comment.

Answer (score 1):

User-mode code should never try to muck around in kernel data structures, and any properly written kernel will prevent it anyway. The best way for user mode code to ensure that an address can be written is to write to it. If the page was not already writeable, the page fault will cause the kernel to make it so.

Nevertheless, the kernel code /cannot/ rely on the application having done so, for two reasons:
1) Even if the application does it properly, the page might be unmapped again before (or after) entering ring 0.
2) The kernel should /never/ rely on application code to do the right thing. It always has to protect itself.

Comment: You seem to be missing the question. The first paragraph was background information, my question which still no one has answered which has an objective answer is, WHERE is the access information for pages stored. I cannot accept this answer because it does not answer that question. Luckily I already found a page that happens to contain that information, as referenced in my answer to my own question.

Answer (score -1):

The access permissions information and page data is stored in the page directory, page table, CR0 and CR3.

More information can be found here: https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  But you'd better keep backups of your filesystem if you start messing around with the kernel's data.  You could corrupt memory in a way that not only crashes, but breaks data on disk leading to FS corruption.  (e.g. if a page was read-only because it's copy-on-write shared with another process, changing your page tables to let you write it instead of letting a page-fault handler making a copy of the physical page before letting your process write the copy.  Or worse, writing non-zero data to the system wide shared zero page used for COW mapping of BSS / anonymous pages)

Comment: The question specified x86-64 and this answer only covers 32-bit paging.

Comment: Also note that CR3 is the *physical* address of the page directory, but even in kernel code paging is enabled so addresses you can actually use are virtual.